# IF variable LSS variable fails when variable is blank

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have the following batch file that will check and compare two variables, however, it fails when one of the variables are blank.. any ideas how to handle a case where LocalVersion can be blank aka the file version.txt does not exist.

test.bat:

```
for /f "tokens=1 " %%a in ('%Tools%\cat.exe version.txt') do set LocalVersion=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 " %%a in ('%Tools%\cat.exe \\UNC_Share\version.txt') do set RemoteVersion=%%a

echo LocalVersion %LocalVersion%
echo RemoteVersion %RemoteVersion%

if %LocalVersion% LSS %RemoteVersion% ( goto :skip )
if %LocalVersion% GTR %RemoteVersion% ( goto :Update)
```

Results:

```
c:\test.bat
LocalVersion
RemoteVersion 4.0.1
4.0.1 was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: to avoid syntax errors, enclose both sides of the comparison with quotes: `if "%var1%" LSS "%var2%" <command>` (your problem here are the spaces)

Comment: Thanks @Stephan. That fixed the issue if "%var1%" LSS "%var2%"

Comment: You should be aware that this is a literal comparison, so `4.0.10` will be less than `4.0.9`.

Comment: Regard that `if` performs string comparisons, unless both sides are purely numeric (`[+-]?(0x)?[0-9]*`) and a comparison operator other than `==` is used; `4.0.1` contains the non-numeric character `.`, so string a comparison is done; this is going to lead to wrong results when comparing `4.0.10` with `4.0.2`, for example...

Answer (score 1):

For comparisons of versions it is strongly recommended not running a literal comparison if the version numbers contain points. It is better to convert the version numbers with points into integers and compare the integers.

Example 1 using multiplications and additions:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "LocalVersion=0.0.0"
set "LocalVersNum=0"
set "RemoteVersion=0.0.0"
set "RemoteVersNum=0"

if exist "version.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=." %%A in ("version.txt") do (
        set "LocalVersion=%%A.%%B.%%C"
        set /A LocalVersNum=%%A * 1000000 + %%B * 1000 + %%C
    )
)
if exist "\\Sever\Share\version.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=." %%A in ("\\Sever\Share\version.txt") do (
        set "RemoteVersion=%%A.%%B.%%C"
        set /A RemoteVersNum=%%A * 1000000 + %%B * 1000 + %%C
    )
)

if %LocalVersNum% LSS %RemoteVersNum% goto Skip
if %LocalVersNum% GTR %RemoteVersNum% goto Update

echo %LocalVersion% is equal %RemoteVersion%.
goto EndBatch

:Skip
echo %LocalVersion% is lower %RemoteVersion%.
goto EndBatch

:Update
echo %LocalVersion% is greater %RemoteVersion%.

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Example 2 using bit operations:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "LocalVersion=0.0.0"
set "LocalVersNum=0"
set "RemoteVersion=0.0.0"
set "RemoteVersNum=0"

if exist "version.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=." %%A in ("version.txt") do (
        set "LocalVersion=%%A.%%B.%%C"
        set /A "LocalVersNum=(%%A << 24) | (%%B << 16) | %%C"
    )
)
if exist "\\Sever\Share\version.txt" (
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=." %%A in ("\\Sever\Share\version.txt") do (
        set "RemoteVersion=%%A.%%B.%%C"
        set /A "RemoteVersNum=(%%A << 24) | (%%B << 16) | %%C"
    )
)

if %LocalVersNum% LSS %RemoteVersNum% goto Skip
if %LocalVersNum% GTR %RemoteVersNum% goto Update

echo %LocalVersion% is equal %RemoteVersion%.
goto EndBatch

:Skip
echo %LocalVersion% is lower %RemoteVersion%.
goto EndBatch

:Update
echo %LocalVersion% is greater %RemoteVersion%.

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Both examples produce the right result for `LocalVersion` being for example `4.0.10` and `RemoteVersion` being `4.0.9` on which a literal comparison like `if %LocalVersion% LSS %RemoteVersion% goto Skip` produces the wrong result.

The command line

```
if "%LocalVersion%" LSS "%RemoteVersion%" goto Skip
```

results always in a literal comparison because the double quotes are not ignored on comparing the strings. So with using double quotes the referenced values are not compared anymore after an implicit conversion from string to integer on both values using an integer comparison, but doing a string comparison.

The solution for avoiding an exit of batch execution because of a syntax error if one of the two `version.txt` files does not exist is an initialization of the used environment variables.

The additional `if exist` condition before each **FOR** is for avoiding an error message on execution of command **FOR** and the appropriate `version.txt` file does not exist.

**FOR** reads the `version.txt` file directly without the tool `cat` which is ported from Unix to Windows and therefore not available by default on Windows. The native Windows command for `cat` is `type` which is most likely not really needed here.